# Particle moving in response to central force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

So I have this question:

> There is a particle moving in response to a central force per unit mass of $$F(r) = {\alpha\over r^2} + {\beta\over r^3}$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. Initially the particle is at $r = \beta^2/3\alpha$, $\theta = 0$ and is moving with speed $4\alpha/\beta$ in a direction making an angle of $\pi/3$ with the radius vector pointing towards the origin. Starting from Newton's Second Law, show that, if $u = 1/r$, then $${d^2u \over d\theta^2} + \frac u4 = {3\alpha\over 4\beta^2},$$ with $$u = {3\alpha\over \beta^2}, {du \over d\theta} = {\alpha \sqrt3 \over \beta^2}$$ when $\theta = 0$.

My attempt at solution:

In polar coordinates, $$\ddot {\mathbf r}= (\ddot r - r \dot \theta)\mathbf e_r+ \left( \frac 1r {d \over dt}(r^2 \ddot \theta)\right) \mathbf e_\theta$$ where $\mathbf e_r$ is the unit vector in the direction of increasing $r$ and respectively for $\mathbf e_\theta$.

Now, if we have a central force, then $\mathbf F=-F(r)*\mathbf e_r$ because the force acts in the direction of $-r$.

Therefore, $$-F(r)\mathbf e_r = m\left[(\ddot r - r \dot \theta)\mathbf e_r+ \left( \frac 1r {d \over dt}(r^2 \ddot \theta)\right) \mathbf e_\theta\right]$$
Equating the coefficients of $\mathbf e_r$ and $\mathbf e_\theta$ gives $$-F(r) = m\left(\ddot r-r \dot \theta^2\right)$$ $$r^2 \dot \theta = h$$
where $h$ is a constant.

Then $$\dot r = {dr \over dt} = {dr \over d\theta}{d\theta \over dt} = {h \over r^2}{dr \over d\theta}  =-h{d \over d\theta}\left(\frac 1r\right)$$
If we let $u = \frac 1r$, then $$\text{radial velocity} \; \dot r = -h{d \over d\theta}\left(\frac 1r\right) = -h{du \over d\theta}$$ $$\text{transverse velocity} \; r \dot \theta = \frac hr = hu$$

So $\ddot r$ becomes $-h^2u^2{d^2u \over d \theta ^2}$.
Thus, $$F\left(\frac 1u\right) = mh^2u^2{d^2u \over d\theta ^2}-\frac mu h^2u^4.$$

Now the problem is, I don't really know how to derive $h$ from the initial conditions.

Comment: You've defined $h=r^2\dot\theta$ which both have definitions in terms of $\alpha$ & $\beta$, no?

Comment: yes, but i can't quite get my head around how to formulate them

Comment: Have you tried substituting them in?

Comment: What would $\dot \theta$ be though?

Comment: It tells you its velocity initially, perhaps you could start there?

Answer (score 1):

What about using Cartesian coordinates, where X is the direction between the initial position and the origin (your direction r), and Y is perpendicular to X s.t. the initial angle between velocity and X, be positive?

Let's try! So,

F(X) = α/X^2 + β/X^3.

$X_0$ = β^2/3α,    $Y_0$ = 0,

$V_{X,0}$ = 4α cos(π/3)/β = 2α/β,    $V_{Y,0}$ = 4α sin(π/3)/β = 2α sqrt(3)/β.

As you see, the movement in the direction X is accelerated, while the movement along Y is with constant velocity. So, we can immediately find the coordinate Y at every time t,

Y(t) = 2α sqrt(3) t/β.

Now, let's deal with X. I don't know the mass, I denote it by M.

M dX/dt d$V_X$/dX = [α/X^2 + β/X^3],

i.e., by multiplying on both sides by dX,

M $V_X$ d$V_X$ = [α/X^2 + β/X^3] dX .

Let's integrate. We get

($V_X$)^2 - ($V_{X,0}$)^2 = -(2α/X - β/X^2) /M .

From this,

$V_X$ = sqrt{(2α/β)^2 - 2α/MX - β/MX^2}

This "pretty" equation we have to integrate for finding X(t). Let's fist get rid of X in the denominator.

X dX/dt = sqrt{(2αX/β)^2 - 2αX/M - β/M}.

We can rearrange this equation as

∫X dX / sqrt{X^2 - β^2 X/2αM - β^3/4Mα^2} = 2αt/β ,

Any idea how to solve this? Try a substitution, X = Q + v, and see if you can get under the square root an expression of the form Q^2 + A^2, or Q^2 - B^2. Such forms are amenable to squares of trigonometric functions, i.e. you can try Q/A = tan(φ), respectively Q/A = cos(φ).

Answer (score 0):

(I am sorry, I was busy and now I continue) I didn't see the possibility to obtain under the square root, a square form.

So, the substitution that I recommended leads to

∫(Q + v) dQ / sqrt{Q^2 + 2(v - β^2 /4αM)Q + [v^2 - 2v β^2 /4αM + (β^2/4αM)^2]

- (β^2/4αM)^2 (1 + 4M/β)]} = 2αt/β .

For obtaining the desired forms we set

v = β^2 /4αM.

Now, I guess that β > 0, otherwise if α and β may have any sign there are too many cases. Our equation in Q yields

∫(Q + v) d(Q) / sqrt{Q^2 - B^2} = 2αt/β,    with    B^2 = (β^2/4αM)^2 (1 + 4M/β)

It's not complicated to integrate this equation,

∫Q dQ/sqrt{Q^2 - B^2} = sqrt{Q^2 - B^2},

and for the remaining part of the integral use Q/B = cosh(φ), d(Q/B) = sinh(φ) .

Just, pay attention that φ is not your angle θ, and after you perform the integral don't forget $X_0$.